# robocopy only if target folder is empty (automatically repeating)

Tags: robocopy

I need to process files in a certain order:

Having two datasouces that produce XML files, lets call them A and B. Both files are meant for same target system, that watches an import directory. However I must achieve that all files from A are transmitted and processed and after that files from B.

I think smart way would be using Robocopy as this can repeat copy action automatically without programming. I need a copy command that works only if target folder is empty.